# if $d|a$ then $|d| \leq |a|$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

statement:-
 Prove that if $d|a$ then  $|d|\le|a|$. where $a\neq0$.

proof:-
      If $d|a$, then there exists $q$ such that
                     $a=dq$.
                  $|a|=|dq|$. 
                $|a|=|d||q|$.

$|a| < |d|$ if $|q| < 1$. 
$|a| = |d|$ if $|q| = 1$.

Combining both we have $|a|\geq |d|$.

$|d| \leq |a|$.

This is the proof I found. what I dont understand is how in the above step $|a|<|d|$, and then in the answer $|d|\le|a|$. the statement has been taken from my text book.

or if anyone has a simple alternate solution it would also help.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: $q$ is an integer. So $\lvert q\rvert < 1$ means $q = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is if $a$ divides $d$ and your proof starts let $d$ divide $a$. Your proof should start let $a|d$ and then each of the remaining steps should have d and a swapped around.

Comment: sorry wrote statement wrong has been corrected

Answer (score 1):

The statement should read:  If $d, a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $d|a$, and $a \neq 0$, then $|d| \leq |a|$.

Proof:  If $d|a$, with $a \neq 0$, then there exists $q \in \mathbb{Z}$, with $q \neq 0$, such that $a = dq$.  Hence, $|a| = |dq| = |d||q| \geq |d||1| = |d|$, with equality holding if and only if $q = \pm 1$.